# SQLite3 MinGW on Windows 10

Tags: windows, sqlite

I want to run sqlite natively in MinGW as I do in Linux.

Tried downloading SQLite3 for Windows. Though it runs in Windows Command prompt, just like it does in Linux, in MinGW terminal the console hangs.

What can I do to ensure the MinGW plays as nice as Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Compile against a version of readline that works properly on Windows.
I build sqlite3 against readline from http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html and have no issues.